# DPRP is disabled. for this merchant in sandbox paypal

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, recurring-billing

I'm trying to integrate paypal payments through card into rails app.

Normal one-time payments are working well. But I keep on getting the above response when I'm trying to make recurring payments. I've tried to enable that feature in paypal developer website but it says

**Note: Live credentials are disabled for direct credit card processing in your app. We are processing your information and will email you when live API credentials are enabled.**

But it is saying same from past few days. I've tried contacting them through online contact us but after three days they replied saying I have to add my credit card to the account. Do I need to add credit card for testing sandbox also?

Answer (score 1):

You need to contact PayPal technical team at https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask , provide your sandbox PayPal account, they will enable DPRP for you.